# how to save location and weather details using gps in android php and mysql?

Tags: php, android, gps

I am new in android programming. i want to save location and weather details in database.Here i want to capture location from mobile number. and from location capture weather details from location details

Comment: Please explain what you have tried?

Comment: Cool story bro. Where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

First Set an Mobile Number Based Registeration for Your Application

Then get The Location Details .[refer this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/)

Then Store the Location Along With Phone Number he Logged in with.
[Refer this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Then With ThirdParty WebServices you can Get Weather Based on GeoPosition.

Answer (score 0):

to find location [use google location api client](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

to find wether integrate third party libary eg [accuweather](http://apidev.accuweather.com/developers/)